# Implementing 3-tier Architecture in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a Simple application where User can Register himself with its Credentials like First Name,Last Name and so on..after clicking on the Register Button it bring him on its mail for Authentication of the User where he will have a link and Clicking on that link it will Redirect to the Login Page.I want to Implement this but using 3-tier Architecture in MVC3.I have created the project by choosing the MVC template and named it as presentation and to get BLL and DAL What should i do?
I have Created my Model:

```
public class Register
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public bool Accept_Term { get; set; }
        public bool Male { get; set; }
        public bool Female { get; set;}
        public string Current_Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Class Library` for your `BLL` and a `Class Library` for your `DAL`, then reference the `BLL` in your `MVC` project and reference your `DAL` in your `BLL` project. Now your `MVC` project will make calls the `BLL`, which in turn will call the `DAL` to actually do data storage/retrieval. Your `BLL` can simply be a passthrough in some instances, while enforcing business rules or other operations in other cases.

You should consider moving your `Model` classes into a separate `Class Library` as well, that way all of your tiers (`MVC`, `BLL` and `DAL`) can all "see" and use your `Model` objects; this of course means that all tiers need a reference to the `Model` project. It is much easier to pass objects around than having methods with parameters for each value of an object.

Comment: Thanks for this..as i am new in 3-tier Architecture and more Comfortable with MVC. So i know to create Model,Controller and View.so Please let me know where i put what? @Karl

Comment: Adding to it, I would call the models as DTO eg. RegisterDTO. Since models have different meaning in MVC, they are basically view models that reside in MVC web app. So, depending upon what you need to see in view, create view models with those properties.

Comment: Right click on your `Solution` in `Solution Explorer`, then choose `Add` -> `New Project`. You should now see the `Add New Project` dialog, it should have `Visual C# - Web` as the filter, change it to just `Visual C#`, then click `Class Library`. Name the library `BLL` and make sure it is saving to the same relative path as your `MVC` project. Rinse and repeat for `DAL`.

Comment: @Sunny - yes, I was going to say that as well, `Model` has a special meaning in MVC, whereas in other tiers of the system it can mean something else. I generally call mine `Domain`, but `DTO` is fine too. Also, you can keep your existing `Model` classes and also create the `Domain` or `DTO` versions, that way you are leaving your existing `MVC` structure in place and adding on top for the other tiers.

Comment: Thanks!!!As of now what I understood that My Original MVC Project will be termed as Presentation in that I have to Delete the Model Folder and i would be having Controller and View Only...Just M confused about the Model which Consists of Properties that i will be accessing in View through Controller but where i have to define it whether in BLL or in DAL?

Comment: @user2477114 - Leave your Model in the MVC project and make three new class library projects; one for your Domain (think of them as the Model classes available to other layers), one for your BLL and one for your DAL. You pass your Domain objects between the Presentation layer (MVC), Business layer (BLL) and Data Access layer (DAL).

Comment: @KarlAnderson can you please give a simple  example.

Answer (score 0):

I think its important to understand why you want a n-tier architecture. If your most important requirement is simplicity, then splitting out your application into n-tiers is not really needed.

However, this choice will result in a downside if you require flexibility. On the other hand, multiple tiers offer flexibility and the cost is the amount of work it takes to build them.

As an example of why you would want to have a n-tier architecture, imagine this scenario. You build an application using Entity Framework 4.x. in your Data Access layer. Then EF 5.0 is then launched and you want to upgrade. If your other tiers are completely ignorant of the Data Access technology that you are using (as they should be), you should have very few issues in upgrading the DAL to a different version or database type. I stress the IGNORANT part. Each layer in the application should be IGNORANT of dependencies in other layers which will allow you to build a decoupled pluggable architecture.

Its a big topic and if you have interest in learning more, I would suggest looking at Domain Driven Design techniques. Don't just have n-tiers for the sake of it. Data Transfer Objects(DTOs)are the objects that carry data between these self contained layers. That is necessary because a "Person" object in the DAL is not the same object as a "Person" object in the Business Layer. DTO's map between the two objects.

Have a look at http://www.dofactory.com/. You will see a simple n-tier MVC application with multiple UIs (winforms, MVC, etc) talking to a self contained Business tier. This should also give you a better understanding of where to put your projects and why they are needed.